# Twig For Loop With Key

Tags: php, twig

Hey how having an issue translating this to twig

```
<?php
foreach( $data as $hash=>$i ){
  $word = ( $i["type"] == 'text' ) ? 'Text' : 'Email';
?>
```

I've tried setting the variables before hand but doesnt seem to be working, quite new to twig

Still having issues the full code is

```
<?php foreach( $data as $hash=>$i ){
$word = ( $i["type"] == 'text' ) ? 'Text' : 'Email';
?>
<input type="radio" name="auth" value="<?php echo $hash; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;Send <?php echo $word; ?> To: <?php echo $i["value"]; ?></br>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your issue with the [Iterating over Keys and Values](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys-and-values) features. As Example:

```
<ul>
    {% for key, value in data %}
        <li>{{ value.type=='text' ? 'Text' : 'Email' }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Hope this help

Comment: Brill thank you :) tried that before just made a slight mistake in it

Comment: Hi @Brien12 you are welcome! what mistake i made? Can you edit my answer for fix the problem?

Comment: Oh no haha, I tried the same thing before but made a mistake in my code, yours is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course if you're not using the array key in your loop, you don't need to use that `key->value` format in your for loops.  You could just do:

```
<ul>
    {% for value in data %}
        <li>{{ value.type == 'text' ? 'Text' : 'Email' }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Similarly in your PHP:

```
foreach($data as $i) {
  $word = ($i["type"] == 'text') ? 'Text' : 'Email';
}
```